# Trying to download an exe file from a website and run it

Tags: java, git, url, download

I am having trouble downloading an exe file from a server and running it. specifically downloading git and installing it automatically. I found some code on another question that isn't quite working, and I don't know why. The parameters I pass it  are:

```
URL url = new URL("http://git-scm.com/download/win");
String fileName = "C:/SETUP/gitinstall.exe";
```

Am thinking maybe it is something wrong with the link I am opening in the URL.
Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

To try and be clear: It gets a file into the directory but when I try to launch gitinstall.exe, I get an error from windows that the file isn't compatible with my version of windows.

However if I download the link through chrome it runs fine. Also The file it downloads is only 8 kb while the file downloaded through chrome is around 15 mb if that helps. Thank you again.

```
public static void saveFile(URL url, String file) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("opening connection");
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(file));

    System.out.println("reading file...");
    int length = -1;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];// buffer for portion of data from
    // connection
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    fos.close();
    in.close();
    System.out.println("file was downloaded");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're downloading the web page, not the file itself. The URL for the file is:

```
https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.2-preview20140411/Git-1.9.2-preview20140411.exe
```

So just do:

```
URL url = new URL("https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.2-preview20140411/Git-1.9.2-preview20140411.exe");
```

Comment: That was quickly. I was still writing when I saw that there was an answer to this. +1 for speed.

Comment: @eam1813 If it worked, mark it as accepted to show future visitors that it worked. Also, you're welcome :)

Comment: @Kyllopardiun I just got lucky... I opened Java newest questions, and this just came up.

Comment: I will. it says I have to wait 8 mins.

Comment: @eam1813 Also, this was a well written question. I appreciate that, and other people with the same issue will too. Keep writing good questions like this. (faith in new SO users/humanity restored).